# Java CompletableFuture using allOf : if one thread throws exception, how to immediately stop execution of all threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, future, completable-future

```
// assume: serviceCall1 throws an exception after 1s, servserviceCall2 runs 10s without exception
CompletableFuture<String> serviceCall1Future = serviceCall1.execute();
CompletableFuture<String> serviceCall2Future = serviceCall2.execute();

CompletableFuture<Void> allOffFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(serviceCall1Future, serviceCall2Future);

// does not work, will be called after thread 2 has finished
allOffFuture.exceptionally( ex -> { allOffFuture.cancel(true); return null; } );

try {
   // waiting for threads to finish
   allOffFuture.join();
} catch (CompletionException e) {
   // does not work, here we come after thread 2 has finished
   allOffFuture.cancel(true);
}
```

If one thread throws an exception, in my case it doesnt make any sense for the other thread(s) to keep on running, so I want them both (all in case of more than 2 threads) to stop . How can I achieve that ?

Comment: you can't really, once a task is started, there is no way to interrupt it. Unless you use a dedicated thread pool, call `shutDownNow` and your code can respond to those interrupts. Otherwise why not do them in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work:

```
CompletableFuture<String> serviceCall1Future = serviceCall1.execute();
CompletableFuture<String> serviceCall2Future = serviceCall2.execute();

CompletableFuture<String> foo1 = serviceCall1Future.whenComplete((result,exception) -> {if(exception != null) serviceCall2Future.cancel(true);});
CompletableFuture<String> foo2 = serviceCall2Future.whenComplete((result,exception) -> {if(exception != null) serviceCall1Future.cancel(true);});

CompletableFuture<Void> allOffFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(foo1, foo2);

// ... rest of your code
```

This cancels the other future when the one completes with an exception.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. Many thanks :) But ... (there is always a but) what if the exception in serviceCall1.execute() is thrown before foo1 and foo2 has been created ?

Comment: @KlausF_007 I would guess the BiConsumer is still invoked. But the documentation doesn't say anything explicit about this case. You might want to try that out.

Comment: `serviceCall1Future.cancel(true)` and the other one, does not interrupt anything, mind the documentation of the `mayInterruptIfRunning` flag. So I can't see how this answers the question, tbh.

Comment: What I want to achieve is, that the main thread (which is in fact a rest service I offer) should immediately return an error if any of the services the rest service is calling fail.
I would say: I do not care about the the servicecall-threads that are still running.

Comment: @KlausF_007 Than this suggestion should probably do what you expect.

Comment: @KlausF_007 if you “do not care about the the servicecall-threads that are still running”, you should not ask “*how to immediately stop execution of all threads*”

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ExecutorService with CompletableFuture, you can use Shutdowns methods like shutdown() or shutdownNow().

> If you want to shut down the ExecutorService immediately, you can call the shutdownNow() method. This will attempt to stop all executing tasks right away, and skips all submitted but non-processed tasks. There are no guarantees given about the executing tasks. Perhaps they stop, perhaps the execute until the end. It is a best effort attempt. Here is an example of calling ExecutorService shutdownNow()

See -> https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html#executorservice-shutdown

Comment: in this case, the code has to be able to react to interrupts, and I am almost sure that in OP's case, this is impossible (try to write some minor code yourself and see). Besides, killing pools like this is a bad idea, especially since OP might need to do this a lot more often.